# Is there and visual tool to see tfs build, msbuild file dependencies?

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

We have a very large and complex bunch of tfsbuild msbuild scripts.
Is there any way to view msbuild or tfsbuild files outside of the text editor?

I'm interested in the connections between Targets and the DependsOnTarget and CallTarget commands.

Answer (score 1):

Try MSBuild Explorer 
http://www.msbuildexplorer.com/

I don't know if you be able to see the "imported" targets, but it could be a start.

Comment: Thanks Carnifex, it's exactly the type of application I'm looking for. But it lacks some features I require. Maybe I should contribute instead of writing my own.